# Let B be the solid tetrahedron bounded by x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, and x+y+z = 1.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $B$ be the solid tetrahedron bounded by $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$, and $x+y+z = 1$.
Assume that the density of $B$ is given by the function $y$. Compute the mass of $B$.

I am having trouble solving this problem. Would I have to first find the integral of the tetrahedron given the bounds, but how would I do that without a function? Also, how would I determine the density of the tetrahedron? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Volume = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y} dz\ dy\ dx = \frac 16\\
Mass = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y} \rho(x,y,z)\ dz\ dy\ dx\\$

and it is given that $\rho(x,y,z) = y$

$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y} y\ dz\ dy\ dx\\
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} yz|_0^{1-x-y}\ dy\ dx\\
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} y(1-x) - y^2\ dy\ dx\\
\int_0^1 \frac 12 y^2(1-x) - \frac 13 y^3|_0^{1-x}\ dx\\
\int_0^1 \frac 16 (1-x)^3\ dx\\
-\frac 1{24} (1-x)^4|_0^1\\
\frac 1{24}$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So how would I determine the exact mass without a function to integrate?

Comment: I am not following your question.  You have a density function.  If you had no information on the density, you cannot determine the mass.

Comment: Okay, so how would I solve that mass integral?

Comment: Here is a step-by-step integration.